# GCP: how to access cloud storage bucket from a VM instance

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, mount

I'm trying to deploy and run a docker image in a GCP VM instance.
I need it to access a certain Cloud Storage Bucket (read and write).

**How do I mount a bucket inside the VM? How do I mount a bucket inside the Docker container running in my VM?**

I've been reading google cloud documentation for a while, but I'm still confused. All guides show how to access a bucket from a local machine, and not how to mount it to VM.
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-gsutil

Found something about [Fuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-f), but it looks overly complicated for just mounting a single bucket to VM filesystem.

Comment: Sadly the only way we found in may company was to use the gcsfuse util - but we did not really found this really overcomplicated. Consider digging deeper on this subject, it might be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage is a object storage API, it is not a filesystem.  As a result, it isn't really designed to be "mounted" within a VM.  It is designed to be highly durable and scalable to extraordinarily large objects (and large numbers of objects).

Though you can use [gcsfuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) to mount it as a filesystem, that method has pretty significant drawbacks.  For example, it can be expensive in operation count to do [even simple operations](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse#cost_breakdown_example) for a normal filesystem.

Likewise, there are many [surprising behaviors](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/semantics.md#surprising-behaviors) that are a result of the fact that it is an object store.  For example, you can't edit objects -- they are immutable.  To give the illusion of writing to the middle of an object, the object is, in effect, deleted and recreated whenever a call to `close()` or `fsync()` happens.

The best way to use GCS is to design your application to use [the API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) (or the [S3 compatible API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating#migration-simple)) directly.  That way the semantics are well understood by the application, and you can optimize for them to get better performance and control your costs.  Thus, to access it from your docker container, ensure your container has a way to authenticate through GCS (either through the credentials on the instance, or by deploying a [key for a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys) with the necessary permissions to access the bucket), then have the application call the API directly.

Finally, if what you need is actually a filesystem, and not specifically GCS, Google Cloud does offer at least 2 other options if you need a large mountable filesystem that is designed for that specific use case:

- [Persistent Disk](https://cloud.google.com/persistent-disk/), which is the baseline filesystem that you get with a VM, but you can mount many of these devices on a single VM.  However, you can't mount them read/write to multiple VMs at once -- if you need to mount to multiple VMs, [the persistent disk must be read only](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#use_multi_instances) for all instances they are mounted to.
- [Cloud Filestore](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/) is a managed service that provides an NFS server in front of a persistent disk.  Thus, the filesystem can be mounted read/write and shared across many VMs.  However it is significantly more expensive (as of this writing, about $0.20/GB/month vs $0.04/GB/month in `us-central1`) than PD, and there are minimum size requirements (1TB).

Comment: The first GiB of Cloud Firestore is free: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/quotas

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix That's true, but you're talking about Fi*R*estore, a database product which isn't relevant for mounting as a filesystem, while Cloud Fi*L*estore is the relevant product in this case.  Indeed, it isn't possible to allocate less than 1 TiB of Filestore capacity.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Storage buckets cannot be mounted in Google Compute instances or containers without third-party software such as [FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse). Neither Linux nor Windows have built-in drivers for Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 0):

GCS VM comes with google cloud SDK installed. So without mounting you can copy in and out files using those commands.

gsutil ls gs://